# Intersection of 2 mongo queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I want to emulate an "&" operator for searching elements in my mongo db.

there are 4 searchable fields `name` `id` `tags` `negative_tags`

for a match to be true, any of these could match.

For instance if I search `a&b`, "a" could be matched in any of the 4 fields and "b" as well. However, they need to both be matched

I tried doing the following

```
Model.or({:name.all => regexps}, {:id.all =>regexps}, {:tags.all => regexps}, {:negative_tags.all => regexps})
```

`regexps` is an array of regexp. For the example given it would be

```
[ /a/i, /b/i ]
```

However, this does not behave like I want, because you need the matches to all happen on the same property.

My other try was to run separate mongo queries for each regexps and take the intersection of the sets.

```
Model.or({:name.in => one_regexp}, {:id.in => one_regexp}, {:tags.in => one_regexp}, {:negative_tags.in => one_regexp})
```

My problem is that I am not sure how to merge the two hashes. `Mongoid` lazily evaluates the queries and returns a `Mongoid::Criteria` object.

I'd like to know how I can do an intersection

Comment: u mean "||" not "&" ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct ways to handle this.  Are you trying to have both regular expressions evaluate per field or can a be true for name and b be true for id?

If it is the latter, I would use a gem for this:

> [gem 'mongoid_search'](https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search)

If it is the former, I'd simply join the array into a single regex:

```
one_regexp.collect {|regexp| "(?=.*#{regexp}" }.join
```

If what you want to do is to apply two RegEx expressions onto each field, simply put both both in nonconsuming patterns and use one regular expression.  This is known as positive lookahead assertion (?=) combined with the .* operator that allows the order to be reversed.

```
/(?=.*a)(?=.*b)/
```